# How to pass variable to the linker file (.sct) and use it to define memory base address

Tags: memory, scatter, keil

I couldn't figure out how to define or include a file in the scatter file to define a memory base address.
There is an example on the arm website however it doesn't work at all. I don't know what I do wrong.

These are the steps I follow,

- [unchecked the tick to change the memory base address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfn3N.png)
- [this is the including of the scatter file and the edit I've made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0mH0.png)
- [And the error from Keil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI8hy.png)

my real aim is to include a file and get the definition from that, but even this simple pre-processing definition doesn't work.

Thank you in advance!